# ¿Cómo se escribe la ruta de archivo en vba para que funcione en Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Estoy tratando de ejecutar una macro que funciona perfectamente en Windows, pero cuando la quiero correr en Mac me muestra el error

> 1004: "No encuentra el archivo"

Así estoy poniendo la dirección:

```vb
Workbooks.Open("/Macintosh HD/Usuarios/carlosstephan/Dropbox/SCEN Const./GastosyPagosSCEN.xlsm")
```

¿Alguien sabe cuál es la forma correcta?

Comment: Además de la respuesta que te indican, prueba quitando el nombre de la máquina en la ruta: `/Usuarios/carlos...`

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente el separador que debe utilizarse en Mac cuando se trabaja con vba es ":" en lugar de "/", sinembargo con el siguiente código puedes averiguarlo:

```
Separador = Application.PathSeparator
```

O si utilizas la ventana inmediato:

```
Debug.Print application.PathSeparator
```

Una vez que sepas que separador utiliza tu equipo, sustitúyelo en la ruta del `Workbook.Open` y no elimines los espacios.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/34933)

Comment: No lo entiendo @toledano ¿por qué dices que eso no da una respuesta? Si se cambia el separador por los dos puntos, debería funcionar ¿no es eso lo que se está preguntando?

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo para contribuir con una respuesta. Solo por las contribuciones de compañeros ayudantes como tu podemos aprender juntos como una comunidad. Cualquier respuesta que encamine al los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudara siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta. __La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores__.

Comment: Casi, Si recuerdo bien debería ser "MacintoshHD:Usuarios:..." pero no ":Machintosh HD:...", cierto? Podrías aclarar eso quizás.

Comment: Lo estoy escribiendo ahora de la siguiente manera: Set GastosyPagosSCEN = Workbooks.Open("MacintoshHD:Usuarios:carlosstephan:Dropbox:SCENConst:GastosyPagosSCEN.xlsm")... y sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Intentalo sin quitar los espacios: `Workbooks.Open("Macintosh HD:Usuarios:carlosstephan:Dropbox:SCEN Const.:GastosyPagosSCEN.xlsm")`

Comment: Lamentablemente sigue sin funcionar. Quite los espacios de los nombres y signos de puntuación.... probé con dos puntos, con la diagonal para los dos lados, comprobé la ortografía mil y una vez.... será alguna configuración del excel?. La verdad no encuentro ninguna otra forma de poner el path del archivo.

Comment: Intenta lo de `Application.PathSeparator` para saber cuál es el símbolo que utiliza tu máquina. No es necesario que quites los espacios ni nada para que funcione. ||| Prueba una cosa: arrastra el archivo hasta una ventana de terminal o shell. Debería escribirse automáticamente la cadena de texto que representa a la ruta de ese archivo. ||| Ojalá pudiera probar yo directamente con tu ordenador XD me está frustrando que no lo consigamos!!!